# How to Flutter scrollbar customisation

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-design

[Possible to scrollbar customisation?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCCdI.png)

I am tried many times but can't customised slider (like image). Scrollbar will show on the side of the list.
Can I set image on the scrollbar or only use the customised theme?
Please help.

Comment: Try looking at [Adding and Customizing a Scrollbar in Flutter](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-scrollbar/).

Comment: You explain your question , show your demo scrollbar type ?